# splitting strings in haskell programming

Tags: haskell

Hi i am trying to do a function input is a list of strings, and the output is again a list of all words occurring in the input.

for example input ["For example,", "love,", "hate."]
output ["For","example","love","hate"]

atm i have this. Any help would be appreciated. Also how can i remove the blank space with just one function and in linear time?
And not using any  existing function

```
split' :: String -> [String]
split' [] = []
split' (x:xs)
     | isBlank x = split' xs
     | otherwise = waitForBlank (x:xs) : split' (drop (length (waitForBlank (x:xs))) xs)

isBlank :: Char -> Bool
isBlank x = if x == ' ' then True else False

waitForBlank :: String -> String
waitForBlank [] = []
waitForBlank (x:xs)
     | isBlank x = []
     | otherwise = x : waitForBlank xs
```

Comment: Hey, no fair -- you said "no built-in functions", but I see a bunch of built-ins in your code already: `(==)`, `(:)`, `drop`, and `length` are built-in functions, and `True`, `False`, `otherwise`, `[]`, and `' '` are built-in non-functions.

Comment: (My previous comment is a bit tongue-in-cheek, but only a bit: you should say carefully what goals you're trying to achieve by avoiding built-ins. Are you satisfying some assignment's requirements? If so, what are the exact requirements? Are you trying to learn how things work right down to the barest bones? If so, why not try implementing `(==)` and `length` and friends so you get the complete experience? Or is there another goal, and if so, what is it? Are you sure avoiding built-ins is in good service of that goal?)

Comment: Sorry I meant existing function

Comment: @dsvjksv Added implementation all user-defined functions.

Answer (score 4):

There's a cool one-line to perform what you need

```
["For example,", "love,", "hate."] >>= words
```

`>>=` has type `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, which takes a function which returns a monadic structure and joins the result into the monadic structure.

If you want to implement `words` by yourself:

```
words' xs =
  let
    waitForBlank (acc, buff) [] = (acc ++ [buff], buff)
    waitForBlank (acc, buff) (x:xs) =
      if x == ' ' then
        waitForBlank (acc ++ [buff], []) xs
      else
        waitForBlank (acc, buff ++ [x]) xs
  in
    fst (waitForBlank ([], []) xs)
```

Or with using `(:)` and `reverse` the result (for better performance):

```
words'' xs =
  let
    waitForBlank (acc, buff) [] = (reverse (buff : acc), buff)
    waitForBlank (acc, buff) (x:xs) =
      if x == ' ' then
        waitForBlank ((reverse buff) : acc, []) xs
      else
        waitForBlank (acc, x:buff) xs
  in
    fst (waitForBlank ([], []) xs)
```

Comment: Isn't this quadratic time due to the use of `++`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes, it is. `(++)` is used here for demonstration purpose, I think the code is more readable. As an option `(:)` can be used with inverting the final result. And I would be glad to hear a better alternative for this

Comment: I don't think there is a better alternative. I just wanted to make this clear for the benefit of those who come across this answer. Reversing is totally fine. Intuitively it looks like this "totally unnecessary waste of resources, if only I could skip it", but really it's linear, so no real harm.